# How to deploy a Java EE project built using eclipse with tomcat to world wide web?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, deployment, web-deployment

How to deploy a Java EE project built using eclipse with tomcat to world wide web? This is my first time that I've built a java EE project and now I need to deploy it into the internet, how can I do it? And my project has a large database that needs to be included, and it is made in mysql workbench

Comment: This is a large undertaking. You need to secure tomcat hosting, database hosting, consider bandwidth costs, this is much bigger than a single SO question. It's an entire project for your team.

Comment: And I don't have a team, i can't find a proper guide on how to do it

Comment: Check out [JVM Hosting](http://www.jvmhost.com/) for a place to deploy to and has MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a war file, if you use eclipse, you have to go to File > Export > Web > WAR File and follow the steps. After that, you put your WAR file into [Home Tomcat]/WebApss or you can load your WAR file with the web console of Tomcat. Now, I don't know how you connect to your databse, if you have your connection with jdbc in your code, then you don't need to configure something else, but if you have a JNDI for your connection, you need to configure the context in your [Home Tomcat]/conf/server.xml file, for example:

```
<Context>
       <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="javauser" password="javadude" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>

</Context>
```

This is the basic configuration for your server and web application, if you need another kind of configuration like security, I recommend you visit the official site of Tomcat.

I hope this information helps you.

Good Luck.